# How do you get kivy to work on a windows subsystem for linux?

Tags: python, kivy

I just installed Kivy and I tried follow a youtube tutorial to set it up on VScode, but when I try to run the tutorial (which is just supposed to be a black screen) I get the following error:

```
[ERROR  ] [Input       ] MTDev is not supported by your version of linux
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Bryan/Documents/CIS Docs/kivy-lab/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    import kivy.input.providers.mtdev
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Bryan/Documents/CIS Docs/kivy-lab/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 84, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.mtdev import Device, \
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Bryan/Documents/CIS Docs/kivy-lab/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lib/mtdev.py", line 29, in <module>
    libmtdev = cdll.LoadLibrary('libmtdev.so.1')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libmtdev.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: x11(['window_sdl2'] ignored)
Couldn't connect to X server
```

For reference this is the program I'm trying to run:

```
from kivy.app import App

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

And I was following along with the first 10 minutes of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8Imtec4ReQ&list=WL

Comment: i think theres a program called xLaunch that will run x11 using your windows display .... I think that will let you run kivy in wsl ... not positive though

Comment: same problem for me. did you find solution?